# CanActivate: Observable Boolean with Socket listener

Tags: angular, canactivate, angular-route-guards

I'm trying to grab a property from a socket from the server like this

```
isVerified() {
    this.socket.emit('verify');

    return new Observable<boolean>(observer => {
        this.socket.on('isVerified', data => {
            observer.next(data)
            observer.complete()
        })
    })
}
```

data will either return true or false so in my route guard I have this

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    this._chat.isVerified()
        .subscribe(
            res => {
                return res
            },
            err => console.log(err)
        )
}
```

but it tells me "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value." and I've been bashing my head trying to figure out to make this work and I've read plenty of other questions to no avail. Console logging res does give me true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`canActivate` return type is **Observable | Promise | boolean**

So you should return an observable in your case:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    this._chat.isVerified();
}
```

Comment: Then what's subscribing for?

Comment: the router module will subscribe to the observable you passed

Comment: Ah, I see where I was getting confused then.